# Bootstrap carousel not working on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to build a carousel feature using the twitter bootstrap library. My code is based off of the simple example provided at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel.

The carousel works fine on desktop browsers chrome and firefox, but when I try the same page on the mobile version of chrome or safari for iOS, the carousel does not render.

I am including bootstrap.css and bootstrap-carousel.js.

What could be the issue here. Also, how do you even go about debugging issues with mobile browsers, as you don't have development tools that are included in the desktop browsers.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. On mobile, carousel has no sliding transition. Just a flashing fade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ignore this question. I had missed a trivial issue that had nothing to do with the library.

Comment: Is there even a way to delete you own question?